# VBA variable not refrencing the array

Tags: arrays, vba

I have a UDT that has a field called arrVals.
The variable totalValue is defined as "instance" of this type.

Then, in some procedure I have:

```
arr = totalValue.arrVals
'--
For i = f To l
    If arr(i, 1) = "" Then
         arr(i, 1) = 1
    End If
Next i
```

After the for-loop, arr(1,1) is 1, but totalValue.arrVals(1,1) has its original value.

I thought arrays are assigned to variables by reference. Could you shed some light as what is going on here?

Comment: If the array contains a value type like an integer as opposed to a reference type like an object then you are always working with a copy not a reference.

Comment: that is true for the value itself. The array is by reference. Like in Java. If you have arr1 and then arr2 = arr1. Then arr2(1) = 0 will change the value for both arrays.

Comment: You can finally try  `totalValue.arrVals = arr`... It will work (or not) depending on what type of object `totalValue` is.

Comment: yup that is a good idea. But I also like to know why this is happening :)

Comment: True for Java, but not for VBA. Arrays don't behave like a reference type.

Comment: You simple load in an array the values of `totalValue` object. You can process the array in a way you want, but the object values will remain unchanged. Why? Because this is the way in which VBA works...

Comment: Thank you all for your answers!